# Grouping placeholders with common input in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've got *n* networks with placeholders for all their inputs and I want to link all of them together to another placeholder (created afterwards) as a common input.

```
class GroupOfNetworks(object):
    def __init__(self,subtask_nets,ob_space):
        self.x_inputs = [st_net.x for st_net in subtask_nets]    #list of network inputs
```

where `st_net.x` is a placeholder declared as follows.

```
class Network(object):
     def __init__(self, ob_space):
          self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + list(ob_space)) `#single network input
```

I'd like to have a single common input to all of these networks so I only need to have one key-value pair in my `feed_dict`. I tried making an assign op on the placeholders (code snippet below) but this throws an error since they're tensors and not variables.

```
#in class GroupOfNetworks...
common_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + list(ob_space),"common_input")
set_input = tf.assign(self.x_inputs[0].x,common_x,"link_subtask_input") # DOES NOT WORK
```

Till now I've used a programmatically generated `feed_dict` (shown below) but this isn't on the graph and cannot be imported while loading the graph from a `.meta` file.

```
def make_common_feed_dict(self,x):
    return {placeholder:x for placeholder in self.x_inputs}
```

Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a single placeholder (and thus the same input) for every network in your network, just use the same placeholder everywhere.

Instead of creating your placeholder inside the object `__init__` method, create it outside and pass it to every object you create.
Do something like this:

```
# Define your network in this way
class Network(object):
     def __init__(self, placeholder):
          self.x = placeholder
```

then, before initializing a `Network` object define the placeholder, then use it

```
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + list(ob_space))

network_a = Network(input_placeholder)
network_b = Network(input_placeholder)
```

Them, supposing that the `Network` obejects got a `get` method to fetch the output tensor, you can execute `network_a` and `network_b` feeding them with the same value:

```
sess.run([network_a.get(), network_b.get()], feed_dict={input_placeholder: value})
```

Comment: Yes, this would work if I had no need to run the `Network` objects independently at all and they could be modified. Are you aware if there any way to handle the case where I cannot modify the `Network` object but only use the reference to the placeholder?